# htaccess | redirect 301 all files to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Sorry to be asking yet another htaccess question but I have searched at length and can't crack it.

I have changed my website to a single page, www.mysite.com/index.html. Previously there were subdirectories and sub-subdirectories, all with a combination of html and other files in them.

I now want all file requests to be directed to the homepage, and for the homepage to display in the browser bar. Eventually I want to remove the old directories and images, but I'm assuming for now that Google needs me to keep them in order to transfer any ranking (is this right?).

There is just one exception to the rule that all traffic should go to www.mysite.com. I have bought another domain www.mysite2.com for SEO reasons. Currently this site has no hosting and is set to redirect to www.mysite.com. If users find www.mysite2.com, I would like them to see content from www.mysite.com but display the domain name www.mysite2.com.

This is the htaccess code I am currently using:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC]

Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mysite2.com/$1 [P]
```

I have several questions/problems:

1) the www.mysite2.com redirect threw a 404 file not found error when i tried to access www.mysite.com. (I am having to test in live production... not great).

2) typing in www.mysite.com/products/ (former directory, still existing) takes me to www.mysite.com/// - it works but is unsightly.

3) typing in www.mysite.com/products/subdir/file.html still takes me to that original file

4) typing in www.mysite.com/lsdhfskdhf (i.e. a non-existent location) displays the homepage but continues to show the string.

5) typing in www.mysite.com/products/ksjdhfkdsjfh (i.e. non-existent location) displays the homepage but without any css formatting (!).

6) Should i be using Redirect 301 instead of RewriteRule? I heard that Google only likes 301 redirect.

I am a bit stuck and would welcome any help! Even if there is a comprehensive guide somewhere to whatever language apache is using in its directories that would be good. Lots of sites claim to this but i haven't found a good one.

Apologies for length.

Thanks
Emma

Comment: There are too many questions in here ideally. Try and focus on the main issue. Provide an example of a source URL and what you expect the rewrite to be. `RewriteRule` issues 301 by default, you have the `[P]` flag set so it is doing a reverse proxy to `site2.com`.

Comment: Please keep one question per thread.